# Comparing a values with ArrayList to MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongo and trying compare ArrayList value with mongoDB and in a result i want List of matching Values.

Let me explain. i have a collection with one document.

```
db.contact.find().pretty(){
"_id" : ObjectId("5718ae778310b8eb61aed7b0"),
"contacts" : [
        {
                "name" : "Sunny",
                "phone" : "9417702107"
        },
        {
                "name" : "Sukhpal",
                "phone" : "9015719419"
        },
        {
                "name" : "anurag",
                "phone" : "9988776655"
        },
        {
                "name" : "vivek",
                "phone" : "8826565107"
        }
]}
```

And Here is my Json with Array List which i will put using HTTPs:

```
{
"contacts":[
     {
         "name":"anurag",
         "phone":"9988776655"
     },
     {
         "name":"Gurwinder",
         "phone":"9015566789"
     }
]}
```

So now i don't know how to this what will query and how to loop throug Array in mongo. Here is my Node.js Mongoos Code:

```
exportcontact = function(req, res, next)
{
var response = {};
    Contacts.find({},function(err,data){
    // Mongo command to fetch all data from collection.
        if(err) {
            response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
        } 
        else if(!data)
            {
               response = {"error" : true,"message" : "No Record Found"};
            }
        else 
        {
            var contactlist = req.body.contacts;

             //************ DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE***************//
              response = {"List":     };

        }
        res.json(response);
    });
};
```

Please help.

Comment: what do you want by comparing a values with ArrayList means what your final goal?

Comment: @shaishabroy i want list of matching results - actually my work is uploade contact list from android phone and return a contact list those already stored in mongodb